# Spring Boot store pictures in database

Tags: html, spring, mariadb

So i am just developing a webapp with spring and want to store some pictures as byte[] in my mariadb. I know how to code a repository which connects to my DB (have seen this in a tutorial) but how can i post these images from my view to an upload service? I'm using pure xhtml sites with css and little javascript.

Also how is it possible to display these images again in HTML?

Greets!

Comment: We don't code your application. Provide some code snippets with your problem and we could help you.

Answer (score 1):

For a web server, it is much easier to put images (and videos, etc) in the file system, then use HTML `<img src=path/to/pic>` to load them.  Meanwhile, store "path/to/pic" in a column in the database table (or otherwise be able to construct it).

The alternatives are clumsy -- Here's one: You can store an image in a `MEDIUMBLOB` then convert it to bin64 and tell `<img...bin64...>` to have the image inline.  Yuck.  (This is not too bad for thumbnails, but inefficient for big images.)